# How Can I change Header and Footer on WordPress Houzez Theme

Tags: wordpress, plugins, header, wordpress-theming, elementor

I tried the Elemetor Header footer Plugin by Creating Header Block and then Designing my own Header but after the update, nothing changed at all. So how can I change/Customize the Header and Footer on Houzez Theme

Comment: Did you find header.php and footer.php in your themes file? Try to change in both files then you will see changes.

Comment: I don't know how to code or code in PHP, what kind of change do you want me to do, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: ok you want to change your header footer with your elementor. You need to set your page properties to elementor canvas. Then you will be able to design your custom header and footer and even all your page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the theme, where I couldn't replace the footer with Elementor Header & Footer Builder. But after using [ElementsKit Elementor addons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/elementskit-lite/), which also has a header and footer builder, the issue was resolved.